# Array initialization within a structure or class

Tags: c++, c, arrays, struct

I was just studying about structures and classes. I created a sample structure for getting familiar with it and tried to initialize an array in it. when I compiled the program it gave me error

```
error: expected ‘:’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘}’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘=’ token
char arr[5] = {2,3,8,67,87};

struct abc{
char a;
char b;
char c;

char arr[5] = {2,3,8,67,87};
};  

struct abc xyz[5];
```

Is array initialization not allowed in declaration of a structure as well as class ?

Comment: I believe `C` and `C++` both may have separate rules......Choose one.

Comment: Even if you choose C++, mention the version since it has a bearing on the answer.

Comment: i just want to know in general that is it possible or not.Did any version of C++ allow to do so.

Comment: Pick ONE SINGLE LANGUAGE. Yes, C++ allows it since C++11.

Comment: OK, since you insist in tagging in one language (without waiting for an answer that works in both), your code works fine in C++, since C++11. See [this example](http://ideone.com/7BPG3k).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess in C you can do like this:

```
struct abc{
char a;
char b;
char c;

char arr[5];
};  

struct abc test= { 5, 2, 3, { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' } };
```

Comment: This is style of declaring in c99. Is it wise to use it ?

Answer (score 1):

In C, you cannot initialize members of a structure in the structure definition. You have to do it when you declare a variable of that structure. In C++, you can do it as part of the constructor.

Comment: I think we can not initialize a member during structure declaration, not definition, structure defining means allocating space for it and giving some value to its members.

Comment: @Subhajit Values for the members can be specified in the structure definition, so that the members take those values when the struct is instantiated (in C++)

Comment: @ juanchopanza, yes I think in c++ this is possible but defining and instantiating are identical, I guess you mean structure declaration

Comment: @Subhajit I was referring to the definition of a structure type - its body.

Answer (score 0):

Completed array initialization is not allowed in struct but you can just initialize the name and type of array without the content. 
In c++

```
struct student{
int age;
string name;
int scoreOf4subject[4];   
};
```

When you need to set the 4 subjects value in array,it would be like:

```
student keny;   
keny.scoreOf4subject={90,91,94,93};
```

Comment: In C++ you can do exactly what OP is doing. See [here](http://ideone.com/7BPG3k).